# Set Long Term Retention Policy for Azure SQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net

Using the SqlManagementClient class, I can retrieve the long term retention (LTR) policy for a given database like so:

```
var ltrPolicy = client.BackupLongTermRetentionPolicies.GetAsync(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, CancellationToken.None);
```

But I'm not sure how to set the LTR policy. Most of the Google results I've seen refer to doing this using the Azure Portal or PowerShell. But I need to do so using c#.

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.ibackuplongtermretentionpoliciesoperations?view=azure-dotnet there are several methods documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the links to the documentation but I already read through that. I was looking for examples especially how to populate some of the BackupLongTermRetentionPolicy parameter properties. In the end, here's what I'm doing though I don't know if it's going to work until I solve a timing issue I am struggling with:

```
var backupPolicy = new BackupLongTermRetentionPolicy
{
    WeeklyRetention = "P52W"
};

await client.BackupLongTermRetentionPolicies.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(
    _azureConfig.DatabaseServerResourceGroupName,
    _azureConfig.DatabaseServerName,
    databaseName, backupPolicy, null, CancellationToken.None);
```